# Do I need to have the Gift to be a Wizard / Warlock etc?

Tags: anima-beyond-fantasy

The group is getting started (I'm the GM), and we're confused - do you need to take the CP Advantage "the gift" in order to be a Mystic class? (Warlock/Wizard/Summoner etc)? It isn't mentioned as a requirement, but it's heavily implied by how the advantage is worded. Is it intended that these classes have a generic -2 Advantage point balance? Makes a huge difference in character generation - thanks in advance if anyone has any insight.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is... A sort of deceptive no. You can play a given class, and there is nothing directly stopping you from doing so. That said, The Gift is 100% necessary for the capacities to both use, and feel magic. Without it, you simply don't have those faculties, nor can you develop them in the future.

That said, a Summoner or a Weaponmaster are just as able to take the gift as anyone else. Additionally, those who take the gift can take magical disadvantages as well, unlike others.

Hope this helps!